# Return a list from the function using OUT parameter

Tags: function, cmake

I would like to create a CMake function as:

```
function(test src_list dst_list)
# do something
endfunction()
```

usage:

```
test(${my_list} chg_list)
```

It means, `my_list` is a list with several fields, and `chg_list` will receive a list modified inside test function.

How can I create a function in CMake to do that?

Comment: Problem is you don't provide the code of the function. Is there `set(${dst_list} <value> PARENT_SCOPE);` in it?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In CMake, functions have their own scope, and by default, all modification of variables are local, unless you pass `CACHE` or `PARENT_SCOPE` as parameter to `set`. Inside a function, if you want to modify a variable in the scope of the caller, you should use:

```
set(${dst_list} <something> PARENT_SCOPE)
```

See [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/function.html):

> A function opens a new scope: see [set(var PARENT_SCOPE)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html#command:set) for details.

Answer (score 8):

Check that inside your function you are `set()`ing not `dst_list` but `${dst_list}`. You need this to return data to the parent scope.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I solved a similar problem which was [marked a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64554215/how-to-make-a-cmake-function-that-collects-targets-in-a-outer-scoped-list-variab?noredirect=1#comment114152538_64554215) of this question. This function takes a string `BinaryName` and adds it to the list `OutVariable` which is available in the parent scope. If the list is not defined it is created. I use this strategy for creating new test targets and adding the name of these targets to a list of targets in the main scope.

Thanks to `@Tsyvarev` for the comments that lead me to figure this out.

```
function(AddToListFromFunction BinaryName OutVariable)
    if ("${${OutVariable}}" STREQUAL "")
        message(STATUS "1")
        set(${OutVariable} ${BinaryName} PARENT_SCOPE)
        message(STATUS "OutVariable: ${OutVariable} ${${OutVariable}}")
    else ()
        message(STATUS "2")
        set(${OutVariable} "${${OutVariable}}" "${BinaryName}" PARENT_SCOPE)
    endif ()
endfunction()
AddToListFromFunction(MyBinary1 MyTests)
AddToListFromFunction(MyBinary2 MyTests)
message(STATUS "MyTests Variable:  ${MyTests}")
```

Comment: While the name of  the function `AddToListFromFunction` looks self-explanatory, it would be useful to provide a little description of your "similar problem" directly in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

These days, with CMake 3.25 or later, you can do this with the `PROPAGATE` clause of the return statement, e.g. as in:

```cmake
function(test dst_list)
  set(${dst_list} "12;34")
  return(PROPAGATE ${dst_list})
endfunction()
```

... which is nicer to read. See also [the CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/return.html) for the details.