# search a list of path in make for include_directories recursively

Tags: cmake

I'd like implement a function in cmake to search a list of path recursively.

Say given a `search_paths`: `/a/b`, `/c`, `/d/e`. I want to have a `return_list` with paths of directories under given search_paths which contains .h files. Here is my function:

```
FUNCTION(R_SEARCH search_paths return_list)
    FOREACH(search_path ${search_paths})
        # POINT A
        R_SEARCH_INNER(${search_path} inner_return)
        SET(all_list ${all_list} ${inner_return})
    ENDFOREACH()
    SET(${return_list} ${all_list})
ENDFUNCTION(R_SEARCH)


FUNCTION(R_SEARCH_INNER search_path return_list)
    FILE(GLOB_RECURSE new_list ${search_path} *.h)
    SET(dir_list "")
    FOREACH(file_path ${new_list})
        GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(dir_path ${file_path} PATH)
        SET(dir_list ${dir_list} ${dir_path})
    ENDFOREACH()
    LIST(REMOVE_DUPLICATES dir_list)
    SET(${return_list} ${dir_list})
ENDFUNCTION(R_SEARCH_INNER)
```

> based on http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/cmake/2012-June/050674.html

However, the inner function call on POINT A will only happen once. 
Could anybody give me some hints or provide a workable solution.

Comment: A `function()` does open its own variable scope. So one thing that you have to change would be to add `PARENT_SCOPE` to your return values (e.g. `SET(${return_list} ${dir_list} PARENT_SCOPE)`)

Comment: Can you also show the code where you call the function, and possibly the input scenario (directory and file structure) and the function output?

Comment: @iLeoDo Out of fairness, I think you should mention/link [the source of your code](http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/cmake/2012-June/050674.html).

Comment: @Florian Thanks for reminding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cmake function, parameter and return](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22487215/cmake-function-parameter-and-return)

Comment: @usr1234567 That was not the only issue with this function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change this:

```
FILE(GLOB_RECURSE new_list ${search_path} *.h)
```

into

```
FILE(GLOB_RECURSE new_list ${search_path}/*.h)
```

See [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html):

> Examples of recursive globbing include:
>
> ```
> /dir/*.py  - match all python files in /dir and subdirectories
> ```

Also, as already suggested (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22517938/2436175)), change:

```
SET(${return_list} ${all_list})
[...]
SET(${return_list} ${dir_list})
```

into:

```
SET(${return_list} ${all_list} PARENT_SCOPE)
[...]
SET(${return_list} ${dir_list} PARENT_SCOPE)
```

---

So the corrected code becomes:

```
FUNCTION(R_SEARCH search_paths return_list)
    FOREACH(search_path ${search_paths})
        # POINT A
        R_SEARCH_INNER(${search_path} inner_return)
        SET(all_list ${all_list} ${inner_return})
    ENDFOREACH()
    SET(${return_list} ${all_list} PARENT_SCOPE)
ENDFUNCTION(R_SEARCH)


FUNCTION(R_SEARCH_INNER search_path return_list)
    FILE(GLOB_RECURSE new_list ${search_path}/*.h)
    SET(dir_list "")
    FOREACH(file_path ${new_list})
        GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(dir_path ${file_path} PATH)
        SET(dir_list ${dir_list} ${dir_path})
    ENDFOREACH()
    LIST(REMOVE_DUPLICATES dir_list)
    SET(${return_list} ${dir_list} PARENT_SCOPE)
ENDFUNCTION(R_SEARCH_INNER)
```

Comment: @iLeoDo Can you please confirm if both changes were necessary?