# Why is my cmake function not assigning value to argument?

Tags: cmake

I write this function that takes a list and appends new values to it. When 
I print it only prints dir.

```
function(test dst_list)
# do somethin
  set(my_list "dir1" "dir2")
  set(${dst_list} ${my_list})
#  message(${dst_list})
endfunction()

set(my_list "dir")
test(my_list)
message("${my_list}")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cmake function, parameter and return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22487215/cmake-function-parameter-and-return)

Answer (score 0):

Trick here if you set() some variable before function and then change it in function and returned so you can read new value, you must add to function bare variable name as in your set() and separately variable value. Other trick you must use is PARENT_SCOPE so set() variables in function can be returned (I think in this case they are rewritten by the same name).

```
function(test var_rtn  var_val)
    set(my_list "dir1" "dir2")
    set(${var_rtn} ${var_val} ${my_list} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()

set(my_list "dir")
test(my_list "${my_list}")
message("ANSWER: ${my_list}")
```

Your output will be now: `ANSWER: dir;dir1;dir2`