# why value of cmake function parameter is literal?

Tags: cmake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(test)


set(MY_VAR "XXXXXX")

function(echo var)
    message(STATUS "var = ${var}")
endfunction()


echo(MY_VAR) # output MY_VAR
```

why the output is **MY_VAR**, it should be **XXXXXX**, is cmake function parameter doesn't pass by value/reference but literal?

it seems that vairable in cmake function call is treated as string, it is a so wired design. when we need to read and modify a variable in function, we have to wirte in this ugly way?

```
set(MY_VAR "XXXXXX")
function(echo var)
    message(STATUS "var = ${${var}}")
    set(${var} "new value")
endfunction()
echo(MY_VAR)
```

Comment: Because you literally pass `MY_VAR` (the string) to the function. Try `echo($MY_VAR)`.

Comment: @tkausl thanks, but vairable in function call is treated as string is a so wired design. when we need to read and modify a variable in function, we have to wirte in this ugly way?
**```
set(MY_VAR "XXXXXX")
function(echo var)
    message(STATUS "var = ${${var}}")
    set(${var} "new value")
endfunction()
echo(MY_VAR) # output MY_VAR
```**

Comment: Well, this is how CMake works.

Comment: If you are looking for the way of returning value from a function via its parameter, then see [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22487215/return-a-list-from-the-function-using-out-parameter). Otherwise I don't understand the question.